# Stopping a poll/voting session if the result is conclusive

Tags: algorithm, math, statistics

Stopping a poll/voting session if the result is conclusive

I'm trying to create an algorithm for stopping a poll/voting session if it has a conclusive result, without waiting for everyone. How many people can vote for a poll is known/defined when creating the poll. Poll question/option count are known as well. Each person can cast one vote for a poll.

For example; a poll defined as

```
Maximum votes: 5
Poll options: 3
```

If three people vote for "option 1", we can end the voting session without waiting for the other 2 because nothing can change the result that "option 1" is won. (option 1 will win by 60%, 80% or 100%)

I come up with following:
If (winning option vote count - second place option vote count) > remaining vote count, stop voting

I'm not sure if it is correct and I'd like to ask for validation and/or for a different algorithm.

Some tests:

```
Max votes: 6, current votes: 4 as
Option 1: 3
Option 2: 1
Option 3: 0

3 - 1 is NOT greater than 2, so we can't stop the voting. 
Validation: remaining 2 people may vote for Option 2, thus changing the result (a tie). 

Max votes: 7, current votes: 6 as
Option 1: 4
Option 2: 2
Option 3: 0

4 - 2 > 1, OK so we can stop the voting. 
Validation: remaining vote can't change the result, Option 1 already won.
```

Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't appear to be about programming.

Comment: From "Ask Question" right column: The community is here to help you with specific coding, **algorithm**, or language problems. If StackOverflow is not the right place, may I ask which network site is suitable for this kind of questions?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you take the top 2 voted options and check if the difference is greater than the votes left then it should win. Here's a pseudocode example (assuming the first two options are the most picked):

```
if ( (option1 - option2) > (maxVotes - currentVotes) ) {
    endPoll();
}
```

Comment: You’re assuming the options are already ordered.  This doesn’t work as written if, say, option3 has the most votes.

Comment: Thanks, this is the same logic as what I come up with in the original post. I take it as a verification.
@pjs You are right, and kroot mentioned that "if you take the top 2 votes" so the answer requires ordering beforehand.

Comment: @Hazard If you are worried about having to sort by top votes you could assign a topVoted and secondVoted variable that will perform the proper checks and update every time a new vote is processed. I don't know if this is more efficient than just sorting it but its an option.